# NavCtrl.push not working on device but working in the browser in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

The "BUY NOW" and the "ADD TO CART" buttons were working perfectly when I run it on the browser but when I install the app on the device, nothing happens when I click on the "BUY NOW" button and "ADD TO CART" button. All buttons are working fine except for the two said buttons ("BUY NOW" and "ADD TO CART"). Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <ion-row col-12 class="float-button">
    <ion-col col-6>
      <button ion-button block color="orange" (click)="goToAddressPage(product,prodquantity)">Buy Now</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>  
      <button  ion-button block color="triams" (click)="addToCart()">Add to Cart</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

TS:

```
    goToAddressPage(product,prodquantity) {

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('isLogin')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.log = data;

          if(this.log == true) {
            if(this.datastock == 0) {
              this.showPopup("In Stock Soon", "The item is currently sold out.");
            }else if(this.datastock >= 1 && this.datastock < this.prodquantity) {
              this.showPopup("Sorry", "You can only avail a maximum of " + this.datastock + " piece(s) of this item");                 
            }else {
              this.navCtrl.push(AddressPage, { product: product ,prodquantity: prodquantity });
              this.prodquantity = 1;
            }
          } else if(this.log == false){
            this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
            this.showPopup("Oops!", "You must login first before you proceed.");
          }
      })
    })

  }
```

APP.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { PayPal } from '@ionic-native/paypal';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { AddressPage } from '../pages/address/address';
import { CartPage } from '../pages/cart/cart';
import { CartpaymentPage } from '../pages/cartpayment/cartpayment';
import { CartorderPage } from '../pages/cartorder/cartorder';
import { CartorderpaypalPage } from '../pages/cartorderpaypal/cartorderpaypal';
import { CartpaypalPage } from '../pages/cartpaypal/cartpaypal';
import { CartshippingPage } from '../pages/cartshipping/cartshipping';
import { CategoryPage } from '../pages/category/category';
import { DetailsPage } from '../pages/details/details';
import { EditaddressPage } from '../pages/editaddress/editaddress';
import { ForgotpassPage } from '../pages/forgotpass/forgotpass';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MyordersPage } from '../pages/myorders/myorders';
import { MyreturnsPage } from '../pages/myreturns/myreturns';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { MyaccountPage } from '../pages/myaccount/myaccount';
import { ProductPage } from '../pages/product/product';
import { OrderPage } from '../pages/order/order';
import { OrderdetailsPage } from '../pages/orderdetails/orderdetails';
import { OrderpaypalPage } from '../pages/orderpaypal/orderpaypal';
import { PaymentPage } from '../pages/payment/payment';
import { PaypalpaymentPage } from '../pages/paypalpayment/paypalpayment';
import { PolicyPage } from '../pages/policy/policy';
import { PopoverPage } from '../pages/popover/popover';
import { ReturnPage } from '../pages/return/return';
import { ReturndetailsPage } from '../pages/returndetails/returndetails';
import { ReviewPage } from '../pages/review/review';
import { SearchPage } from '../pages/search/search';
import { SearchresultsPage } from '../pages/searchresults/searchresults';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';
import { SubcategoryPage } from '../pages/subcategory/subcategory';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { TermsPage } from '../pages/terms/terms';

import { ProviderOneProvider } from '../providers/provider-one/provider-one';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AddressPage,
    CartPage,
    CartpaymentPage,
    CartpaypalPage,
    CartorderPage,
    CartorderpaypalPage,
    CartshippingPage,
    CategoryPage,
    DetailsPage,
    EditaddressPage,
    ForgotpassPage,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    MyaccountPage,
    MyordersPage,
    MyreturnsPage,
    ProductPage,
    OrderPage,
    OrderdetailsPage,
    OrderpaypalPage,
    PaymentPage,
    PaypalpaymentPage,
    PopoverPage,
    PolicyPage,
    ReturnPage,
    ReturndetailsPage,
    ReviewPage,
    SignupPage,
    SearchPage,
    SearchresultsPage,
    SubcategoryPage,
    TabsPage,
    TermsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AddressPage,
    CartPage,
    CartpaymentPage,
    CartpaypalPage,
    CartorderPage,
    CartorderpaypalPage,
    CartshippingPage,
    CategoryPage,
    DetailsPage,
    EditaddressPage,
    ForgotpassPage,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    MyaccountPage,
    MyordersPage,
    MyreturnsPage,
    PaymentPage,
    PaypalpaymentPage,
    ProductPage,
    OrderPage,
    OrderdetailsPage,
    OrderpaypalPage,
    PopoverPage,
    PolicyPage,
    ReturnPage,
    ReturndetailsPage,
    ReviewPage,
    SignupPage,
    SearchPage,
    SearchresultsPage,
    SubcategoryPage,
    TabsPage,
    TermsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ProviderOneProvider,
    DatePipe,
    PayPal,
    Network
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Login.TS

```
import { ProviderOneProvider } from '../../providers/provider-one/provider-one';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public storage: Storage, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public http: Http, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public dataService: ProviderOneProvider, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public nav: NavController) {

    this.LoginForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6),Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
      contactno: [],
      vcode: []
    });

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('isLogin')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.active = data;
      })
    })

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('customer')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.store = data;
      })
    })

  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {

    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                     content: "Please wait ..."
                });
    loader.present();

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('isLogin')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.active = data;
      })
    })

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('customer')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.store = data;
        loader.dismiss();
      })
    })

    this.date = Date.now();
    this.date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(this.date);
    this.emaillog = "";
    this.passlog = "";
    this.customer_active = false;
    this.customerStatus = false;
    this.customerDeactivated = false;
  }

  createAccount() {
    let createAccount = this.modalCtrl.create(SignupPage);
     createAccount.present();
  }

  login() {

   this.submitAttempt == true;
   if(this.LoginForm.valid) {

       let loginData = { email: this.LoginForm.value.email, password: this.LoginForm.value.password };
          let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
              content: "Please wait ..."
          });
          loader.present();
          this.dataService.login(loginData).then((result) => {
          this.LoginData = result;
          loader.dismiss();

          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.LoginData, 'customer')) {
              this.customerStatus = true;
              this.customer_active = false;
              this.customerDeactivated = false;
          } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.LoginData, 'cus_active')) {
              console.log("Email Address: " +this.emaillog);
              this.customerStatus = false;
              this.customer_active = true;
              this.customerDeactivated = false;
                let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                     content: "Please wait ..."
                });
                loader.present();
                this.http.get('http://capstone20172018.xyz/TOMS/api.php/customer?filter=customer.customer_email_address,eq,'+this.emaillog+'&transform=1')
                  .map(res => res.json())
                  .subscribe(data => {
                      loader.dismiss();
                      this.validcustomer = data.customer;
                      this.id = this.validcustomer[0].customer_id;
                      this.cuscode = this.validcustomer[0].customer_validation_code;
                      this.contactno = this.validcustomer[0].customer_contact_no;
                      console.log("Verification Code DB: " +this.cuscode);
                  }, (err) => {
                      console.log("Something went wrong." +err);
                });
          } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.LoginData, 'customer_deactivated')) {
              this.customerDeactivated = true;
              this.customerStatus = false;
              this.customer_active = false;
          } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.LoginData, 'customer_block')) {
              this.customerDeactivated = false;
              this.customerStatus = false;
              this.customer_active = false;
              this.showPopup("Sorry","Your account is temporarily block");
          } else {
              this.storage.ready().then(() => {
              this.storage.set('customer', this.LoginData);
              this.storage.set('isLogin', true);

                let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                     content: "Please wait ..."
                });
                loader.present();

                this.storage.ready()
                  .then(()=>{
                    this.storage.get('customer')
                    .then((data)=>{
                      this.store = data;
                      this.active = true;
                      loader.dismiss();
                    }, (err) =>{
                      console.log("Something went wrong. " +err);
                      loader.dismiss();
                    })
                  })

              });
          }
        });
  } else {
    this.required = true;  
  }
}

 logout() {

  let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: "Please wait ..."
        });
        loader.present();
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {
          this.storage.remove('customer')
          this.storage.set('isLogin', false)
          this.store = null;
          this.emaillog = "";
          this.passlog = "";
          loader.dismiss();
    });
 }

 forgotPass() {
  this.nav.push(ForgotpassPage);
 }

 activate(customer) {

  let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Please wait ..."
    });
    loader.present();

    if(this.mycode==this.cuscode) {

        this.http.put('http://apiURL/xxx/api.php/customer/'+this.id, JSON.stringify(this.activated))
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.showPopup("Success","Account Activated.");
            this.customer_active = false;
            loader.dismiss();
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.showPopup("Oops!", "Something went wrong.");
            loader.dismiss();
          });

    }else {
      this.wrongcode = true;
      loader.dismiss();
    }

 }

 resendCode() {

    let signupData = { contactno: this.LoginForm.value.contactno, email: this.LoginForm.value.email, code: this.LoginForm.value.vcode };
    this.dataService.notif(signupData)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.showPopup("Success","Verification Code successfully sent.");
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 }

  showPopup(title, text) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: data => {
            if (this.createSuccess) {
              this.nav.popToRoot();
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you use lazy-loading ? and please update code and share app.module.ts and LoginPage.ts

Comment: yes I'm using lazy loadings

Comment: so update your code i will resolve it....

Comment: check my answer i already post that..

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change in `goToAddressPage(product,prodquantity)` function**

```
   goToAddressPage(product,prodquantity) {

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('isLogin')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.log = data;

          if(this.log == true) {
            if(this.datastock == 0) {
              this.showPopup("In Stock Soon", "The item is currently sold out.");
            }else if(this.datastock >= 1 && this.datastock < this.prodquantity) {
              this.showPopup("Sorry", "You can only avail a maximum of " + this.datastock + " piece(s) of this item");                 
            }else {
              this.prodquantity = 1;
              this.navCtrl.push(AddressPage, { product: product ,prodquantity: prodquantity });

            }
          } else if(this.log == false){
            this.showPopup("Oops!", "You must login first before you proceed.");
            this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
          }
      })
    })

  }
```

**Refactor `Login.ts` code. Its not an error its for best practice**

```
import { ProviderOneProvider } from '../../providers/provider-one/provider-one';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public storage: Storage, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public http: Http, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public dataService: ProviderOneProvider, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public nav: NavController) {

    this.LoginForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6),Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
      contactno: [],
      vcode: []
    });

    this.storage.ready()
    .then(()=>{
      this.storage.get('isLogin')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.active = data;
      });

      this.storage.get('customer')
      .then((data)=>{
        this.store = data;
      });
    })


  }
```